# How can i handle two way binding in MVI architecture?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow, single-source

I see many articles handling two way binding with MVVM. But i want to handle this issue with single source of truth. I dont want to create multiple stateflows for this case. I have a StateFlow which has all view state inside entity. How can i provide to sync with multiple EditText values to the StateFlow ?

I have added multiple TextWatcher's to sending event to ViewModel but this way causes so boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

I got your question and I think that you need to use viewBinding feature,

> so the first step you need to enable viewBinding features in your gradle (module).

```
android{
   buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true //this is mandatory
   }
   ...
}
```

then you can bind your view
I use my code as example

> inside the activity class
> you can declare viewBinding of your activity using lateinit and inflate your activity inside onCreate fun

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)
       ...
    }
}
```

> and finally you can easily access your view using binding val

example

```
binding.textView.text = "example"
```

the code above will be similar to

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view).text ="example"
```